# how do i use and asp:linkbutton with an event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Im use to use an asp:button with this

```
Private Sub cmdSignOut_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSignOut.ServerClick
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
End Sub
```

But how can i use this event, so i can call it from an asp:linkbutton !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the linkbutton's `OnCommand` property.

```
<asp:LinkButton
   id="lb_sign_out"
   runat="server"
   Text="Sign Out"
   CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem("User_ID") %>' 
   CommandName="Delete" 
   OnCommand="cmdSignOut_ServerClick" />
```

I'm not sure how you're storing the user's id -- you may need to change (or simply remove) the command argument and command name.

Comment: thx Tamago i deleted the CommandArgument and CommandeName, bc i cant see what i need em for, and its works fine, THX

Answer (score 0):

Isolate your code:

```
Private Sub cmdSignOut_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSignOut.ServerClick
    DoSomeStuff()
End Sub   

Private Sub DoSomeStuff()
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
End Sub
```

Now you can just call `DoSomeStuff` instead.